# Unity Animation Event - No function selected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, events

I googled and tried a lot and right now just going crazy, cause its just a simple thing that takes to much time to be solved.
So in the web there are two types of posts:

1. Console gives error "No function selected" and the solution is that some ppl added by accident an animation event and didnt set it up. **<-This not what Im looking for**
2. I added an animation event to my clip, but clicking on the drop-down "Function" says "No Function Selected"and does not let me select anything. **<- This is what Im looking for.** This kind of posts never got an answer.

**This is how it looks like**:
[image]

**Hierarchy:**

Object 1
  Object 1.1 **<-** Has a script from where I start animations
  Object 1.2 **<-** Has the animator. Rotate and scale object 1.2

**More Information:**
Yes, I selected at first my Object 1.2, selected then the right clip in the Animation-Window and added an animation event.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> This kind of posts never got an answer

Please allow me to doubt that.

---

Simply make sure that your setup fulfills the following conditions:

[`AnimationEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html) requires

- the Component from which you want to use a method is attached to the **same `GameObject` as the `Animator`** component
- the method you want to call has accessibility and return type `public void`
- the method you want to call has **none or maximum one** parameter
- the supported types for the parameter are `int`, `float`, `string`, [`UnityEngine.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html), [`AnimationEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationEvent.html)

---

Since your script is on another GameObject you could redirect the call e.g. like

```
public Redirector : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Either drag in via Inspector
    [SerializeField] private ScriptOnOtherObject _scriptOnOtherObject;

    // or get at runtime if you are always sure about the hierachy
    private void Awake()
    {
        _scriptOnOtherObject = transform.parent.GetComponent<ScriptOnOtherObject>();
    }

    // and now call this from the AnimationEvent
    public void DoIt()
    {
        _scriptOnOtherObject.TheMethodToCall();
    }
}
```

Comment: the only reason why it didnt show up was because the method was from Object 1.1 (in my example) and the animator is on Object 1.2.

Comment: Not sure if this has changed since this was posted but `bool` isn't supported according to https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html

Comment: "The parameter can be a `float`, `string`, `int`, or `object` reference, or an AnimationEvent object."

Comment: @RichardMuthwill good point .. and no this hasn't changed ;)